Converting a Continuous Variable Into a Larger Ordinal Categories for Logistic Regression?
Similar to TB, patients with nontuberculous mycobacterial pulmonary disease need to cough up sputum in order to be diagnosed with the disease. However, there is no data on how much volume is needed to achieve sufficient sensitivity.
I'm currently studying the question whether sputum volume (x) is associated with culture positivity (y).
In a logistical regression model in which you analyze the association between dependent variable Y (culture positive) and independent variable X, which is originally the continuous variable of sputum volume, if you notice the relationship is not linear and there may be threshold effects, can you convert variable X from a continuous variable into larger discrete ordinal values of unequal weighting and analyze it a numerical value (as opposed to purely categorical value)?

Do not discretize your data. This loses information for no gain at all. For one, it treats values in the same bucket as identical, and values that are close together but in different buckets as completely different, which makes zero biological sense. What is the benefit of breaking up a continuous predictor variable?
If you suspect nonlinearities, use spline transforms instead. I very much recommend Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies and his R packages. (Note that you need to be careful about inference and p values if you "tune" your model on your actual data.)

Thanks, Stephan!
